# Rails: How to I render an existing view in another view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried to make sense of layouts but got lost..
Also googled & looked at other similar questions on SO but none of them helped.

Say I have MVC's (scaffold'ed) for A and B, creating their `..views/A/index.html.erb` and `..views/B/show.html.erb` among the rest.

A's index method sets a @a_collection.

Within B's show view I want to:

```
<p>..stuff for B..</p>
<%= render A's index %>
<p>..some more B-stuff</p>
```

How can I render A's index in that place in B's show?

Comment: You don't typically render a view inside of another view. You [use partials to share code across views](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials). If you REALLY wanted to render another view  you could do it with `render template: "a/index"` but its the wrong answer to the wrong question.

Comment: @max: I've read those guides & got lost; if I change the `index..` (for partials) to `_index..` the A.index method is not called, I get 'undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass' on `a_collection`

Comment: You're still thinking it about it wrong - extract the code you want to resuse from the index into a partial and then render that partial from the a/index and b/show view. Don't render the complete index view - its not a good way to structure your code.

Comment: @max: just tried that & get 'nilclass'-error from B's show

Comment: Nil errors are solved by basic debugging. You can do it. All the answers you need are right in that guides article - you just need to work on understanding the basic concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You don't typically render a view inside of another view. You use partials to share code across views. For example:

```
# app/views/products/_product.html.erb
# this is the code you want to reuse
<p>Product Name: <%= product.name %></p>
```

```
# app/views/products/index.html.erb
<%= render @products %>
```

```
# app/views/stores/show.html.erb

<h1><%= @store.name %></h1>

<h2>Our Products</h2>
<%= render @store.products %>
```

`<%= render @products %>` is shorthand for `<%= render partial: "product", collection: @products %>`.

This is just the implicit rendering - in many cases you'll want to add more partials and render them explicitly. Like for example the `_form.html.erb` partial that you'll find in the scaffolds thats used to share a form between the create and edit views.

Think of partials like the view equivilent to a function - ideally they should take some input in the form of locals and result in a chunk of HTML.

Comment: Tested this, renamed A.index to A._pindex, created new A.index, and need to do  `render 'pindex' ` . In B.show the only one that gets through is `render 'A/pindex'` but the fails with 'nillclass' on @a_collection.

Comment: Like I said - everything you need to know is in the guides article. I can't help you with handholding and step by step debugging on code I can't even see.

Comment: Got it to work by setting @a_collection in B.show and then doing `render 'A/pindex', collection: @a_collection`. No `partial:`-keyword used.

Comment: The partial keyword is implied if you're rendering from inside a view.